Changing color line and legend order in timeplot of Parameters Variation experiment
Dears,
I used a time plot to check a parameter variation experiment, but all the lines are the same colour. at the same time, the legent isn´t organized as ascending order, e.g.

time plot in parameter variation
I couldn't set different colours for each run or legend order option. All comments are welcome.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I will assume you are adding the DataSet dynamically (as if you do it on the UI you get the option to pick the color).
There are several ways to call addDataSet, that can be seen on the official documentation under TimePlot
The call you should be using is this one, which allows you to specify format options including Color.
void addDataSet(DataSet ds, String title, Color color, boolean drawLine, int interpolationType, float lineWidth, int pointStyle)

